# Declare empty dictionary in codable class

Tags: ios, swift, codable, decodable, encodable

I want to send empty Dictionary like this

```
“visitor_attrs”: {}
```

I try to implement empty dictionary in a class. In the decoder I get the warning:

> No 'decode' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'Dictionary'

How can I do this?

```
var data: String
var event: String
var visitorAttrs: Dictionary<String, Any>

init(data: String, event: String) {
    self.data = data
    self.event = event
    self.visitorAttrs = [:]
}

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case data
    case event
    case visitorAttrs = "visitor_attrs"
}

required public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.data = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .data)
    self.event = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .event)
    self.visitorAttrs = try container.decode(Dictionary<String:Any>.self, forKey: .visitorAttrs)
}

public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(self.data, forKey: .data)
    try container.encode(self.event, forKey: .event)
    try container.encode(self.visitorAttrs, forKey: .visitorAttrs)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by having Any as value in your dictionary and Any isn't decodable, replace it with String (or whatever data type you have) and this should work.

```
var visitorAttrs: Dictionary<String, String>
```

Fix this issue and you will get the expected behaviour

```
let item = Item(data: "data", event: "event") //I gave your class the name Item
let encoder = JSONEncoder()

do {
    let data = try encoder.encode(item)
    if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(str)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Output is

> {"event":"event","visitor_attrs":{},"data":"data"}

Comment: Another option would be using empty `Codable` type here. Like `struct Stub: Codable {}`. It will work too, and doesn't need to supply irrelevant type info like `<String, String>`.

Comment: @user28434 Yes but not if it sometimes will contain data, the full use-case is not clear.

Comment: Indeed, but if it's contains data it still may be better to use `Codable` class, only with all the fields being `Optional`. I doubt all values would be of the same type.

Answer (score 2):

My assumption is that because the **visitorAttrs** is empty on your JSON response it fails to get a dictionary out of it as there is none.

You have two options (as far as I know)

1. Make the **visitorAttrs** property optional, that way if you don't have anything it will still be able to decode properly, or,
2. Set the value of **visitorAttrs** to an empty dictionary if it fails to decode it

```
let visitorAttrs = try? container.decode(Dictionary<String:Any>.self, forKey: .visitorAttrs)
self.visitorAttrs = visitorAttrs ?? [:]
```